# Multimensional array cannot print values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array coming from JSON.  I cannot seem to get to print one value from all.  It either gives me nothing or says `array`.  I need to print all the `zip_code` fields.

```
 $spit = json_decode($result);
```

Yields:

```
stdClass Object
   (
  [zip_codes] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [zip_code] => 33779
                [distance] => 9.513
                [city] => Largo
                [state] => FL
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [zip_code] => 33771
                [distance] => 9.188
                [city] => Largo
                [state] => FL
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [zip_code] => 33760
                [distance] => 9.989
                [city] => Clearwater
                [state] => FL
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [zip_code] => 33770
                [distance] => 8.525
                [city] => Largo
                [state] => FL
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [zip_code] => 33786
                [distance] => 8.153
                [city] => Belleair Beach
                [state] => FL
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [zip_code] => 33764
                [distance] => 7.651
                [city] => Clearwater
                [state] => FL
            )

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [zip_code] => 33756
                [distance] => 6.373
                [city] => Clearwater
                [state] => FL
            )
```

I have tried to access with `$zip=$spit->zip_codes->zip_code;` and  `$zip=['zip_codes']['zip_code'];`

I am sure I am just missing the obvious but have tried about 20 ways to echo it out with no luck.

Comment: Try `$zip = $spit->zip_codes[0]->zip_code;`

Comment: This give me only the first zip code not the whole array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing JSON array after json\_decode/multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934660/accessing-json-array-after-json-decode-multidimensional-array)

Comment: So you loop through and access `$spit->zip_codes[$i]->zip_code` instead.

Comment: I gave you a hint to access *one* zip code. Just loop through it if you want all the zip codes.

Comment: Thanks!  Changing the json_decode to true made it work

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$spit = json_decode($result);
```

to

```
$spit = json_decode($result,1);
```

This will convert JSON into an array and then you can print the zip code as

```
print_r($spit["zip_codes"]);
```