# Insert from json array after json_decode in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [lead_id] => 1
        [employee_id] => 2
        [update_date] => 2016-11-25
        [lead_status] => Fresh Leads
        [reason] => Deal Won
        [notes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [notes] => Notes 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [notes] => Notes 2
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [notes] => Notes 3
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [lead_id] => 1
        [employee_id] => 5
        [update_date] => 2016-11-25
        [lead_status] => Fresh Leads
        [reason] => Deal Won
        [notes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [notes] => Notes 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [notes] => Notes 2
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [notes] => Notes 3
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [lead_id] => 3
        [employee_id] => 2
        [update_date] => 2016-11-25
        [lead_status] => Fresh Leads
        [reason] => Deal Won
        [notes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [notes] => Notes 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [notes] => Notes 2
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [notes] => Notes 3
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

This is my json array.
How can I get the values of each fields from this array?
Please help

Comment: This is not JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing JSON array after json\_decode/multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934660/accessing-json-array-after-json-decode-multidimensional-array)

Comment: this is php array. `foreach ($arr as $ar){echo $ar['lead_id']; // and so on for others}`

Comment: Ramya this is an array not JSON object

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid json array, 
you can validate your json arrays or json objects using [following url](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

this the simple code of read json object using php

```
$data = '{
    "name": "Saman",
    "age": "19",
         "records":[{
                "subject1":"Maths",
                "marks":"67"

            }]
        }';

$character = json_decode($data);
echo "Name :".$character->name;
echo "Age :".$character->age;
```